# SharePoint metric for Document library : SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Using O365 SharePoint online and looking for a way to get the document library folder usage (metrics) by users who have accessed each folder. I have tried the Most popular items and Popularity Trends but they do not give the metrics that I need. I need the library usage by user level. Is there a way to get this information? Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the Global admin access to my login and through the following URL i was able to get the details,
https://protection.office.com/#/unifiedauditlog

You need to specify the "Accessed File" and mention the Document library link to get the details of the Audit log

Answer (score 1):

To get the usage of the document library, you can go to library settings-> Generate file plan report. It will generate the report as excel file for the document library.
[image]

[image]

To get who access the folder on a given day, you could use the audit log report.

Go to site settings->Site Collection Administration->audit log reports->click “Run a custom report”->set the save location, and restrict the report to the library, and set the date range, and in the events select “Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties”.
 [image]

[image]

More reference:

[View audit log reports.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527)

Comment: Okay this report get the details of all the folder inside the document library. But it does not show who accessed each folder on a given day. Is there a way to get that information please?